# Running phpmyadmin on one cloud server and trying to access mysql on another cloud server

Tags: mysql

Just curious, if you have mysql on one server, and phpmyadmin on another server, mysql doesn't have to be running for PMA to get data from the remote mysql database right? (don't hate me if this is a stupid question!)

Answer (score 2):

mysql has to be running and listening on a TCP socket on your mysql server machine.  On the machine running phpmyadmin, you'd have to have mysql client libraries and mysql support for php installed, but this machine does not need its own copy of mysql server.

Comment: right, but i just want to make sure mysql doesn't have to be running on BOTH machines for phpMyAdmin to access the remote machine. for some reason i wasn't sure if PMA needed mysql.sock to talk to the other machine (or not needed but could use that socket or something)

Comment: ahh, got it.  I've updated my answer accordingly